# Code editor doesn't show in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am working on flutter project using android studio and it was working without any problem, but now I opened the project again occurred this issue doesn't show edit files just an empty view, I don't know the reason
[showing me like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvWka.png)

I tried to restart Ide and Invalidate caches, and also restarted my computer but nothing happened